# Finding a string in an io.ReadCloser without making large allocations

Tags: http, go, memory

I have a large `io.ReadCloser` that I got from an `http.Request` in my HTTP handler func. I need to proxy the request to another server, but first I want to find a string in the body matching a regex like `Title: (\w+)`. This is hard -- copying the whole body into a new buffer to operate on takes up way too much memory, and I've tried using [regexp.FindReaderSubmatchIndex](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindReaderSubmatchIndex) but it only gives me the index of the result, not the actual string.

What's the best way to do this? Tokenizers and JSON decoders and such seem to work on io streams, and this is a really simple use case for that. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: It seems to me that you can read it multiple times, each time read a piece into a buffer and then find the match in the buffer. Is it viable?

Comment: If I wrap the body in a `bufio.Scanner` then absolutely I could read line-by-line. My difficulty now is leaving the body untouched for when I proxy it.

Most examples of 'resetting' a body in this way use something like this:

    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)
    req.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(body))

which still allocates a bunch of the memory at once.

Comment: @JackBritton:  If you're low on memory, a temporary file will work as well.

Comment: That's an idea I hadn't considered. The idea would be to read the body, writing it out to a temporary file, and then copy the file contents back into the request so I can proxy it? I'll give that a go.

Comment: This will absolutely be a performance hit though, correct? Especially in the middle of a request...

Comment: @JackBritton: Benchmark it and find out.  It should be noted that Go already uses temporary files for incoming HTTP requests when the request body is above a certain threshold.

Comment: @JackBritton Can't you obtain a copy of body with request.GetBody() and then wrap this copy in bufio.Scanner?

Comment: @Uvelichitel request.GetBody() returns nil in this context because I'm receiving a client request.

@Tim Cooper The fact about temporary files being used internally is very interesting. I will take a look at this in a moment.

I'm going to try using `io.Pipe` first to parse the body while streaming it to the next step in the code, I will post my findings after I explore that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution. I placed a pipe between the response body and its reader, and wrapped the reader with an `io.TeeReader` so it would write to the pipe as I read from it. I wrapped that in a `bufio.Scanner` and scanned lines. After I was done scanning lines, I was sure to consume the remainder of the body (with `io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, body)`) so that the rest of the body would be written to the pipe.

```
if request.Body == nil {
    proxy(request)
    return
}

// The body is *not* nil,
// so we're going to process it line-by-line.

bodySrc := request.Body             // Original io source of the request body.
pr, pw := io.Pipe()                 // Pipe between bodySrc and request.Body.
body := io.TeeReader(bodySrc, pw)   // When you read from body, it will read from bodySrc and writes to the pipe.
request.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(pr) // The other end of the pipe is request.Body. That's what proxy() will read.

go func() {

    scanner = bufio.NewScanner(body)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        x := scanner.Bytes()
        if processLine(x) {
            break
        }
    }

    // We're done with the body,
    // so consume the rest of it and close the source and the pipe.
    io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, body)
    bodySrc.Close()
    pw.Close()

}()

// As proxy reads request.Body, it's actually keeping up
// with the scanning done in the above goroutine.
proxy(request)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use io.TeeReader for that and pass special writer to the TeeReader constructor. Consider following as a pseudocode because there are some edge cases that we don't handle here:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "regexp"
)

type Finder struct {
    Regexp *regexp.Regexp
    match  string
}

//Write implements io.Writer interface
func (f *Finder) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    if f.match == "" {
        f.match = string(f.Regexp.Find(p))
    }

    return len(p), nil
}

func Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    f := &Finder{
        Regexp: regexp.MustCompile("Title: ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)"),
    }

    r.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(io.TeeReader(r.Body, f))

    //pass request to another server

    fmt.Println(f.match)
}
```

Comment: Pretty good but the byte arrays passed to Finder.Write could only include part of the string we're looking for. I'm posting my solution using pipes and scanners now.

Comment: To clarify, the reason I don't think this sould work is that Finder.Write can be called with byte slices of arbitrary length. For example: "apsdiofadsf Titl", followed by "e: (Jack Britton's 7 Pillars of Success) pasdfpajisdf".

Comment: Guys, read my answer carefully. I pointed the author of the question to the right direction as he/she was asking. I also wrote that there are edge cases. And these are edge cases you're talking about.

Comment: How would you avoid this particular edge case, with the code you've given here? Is there a way to force Finder.Write to be written to line-by-line, or in such a way that we don't split the string I'm interested in down the middle?

Comment: In case there's no match you can keep last 7 bytes in the finder state (length of the "Title: ") and look for the match within last 7 bytes + next p. Similarly in case when you found a substring you can check if it is not a suffix of "p" if so you can keep the substring in the temp buffer inside the finder. This will be an easier solution without involving scanner, pipes and goroutines.

Comment: Buffering old input so that you can contextualize incoming data == building your own scanner. In general imo using a scanner is also more extensible.. you can scan by words, lines, or a custom split function, and you won't have to worry about maintaining a temporary buffer.

Comment: I don't say that your solution won't work I just say that for your question my solution would be simpler/enough/faster

Comment: We'd have to run a benchmark, I'm not sure which is faster. Either way thank you for the solution! Defining a custom writer isn't something I'd considered, and I might use it in the future.